# Override module function in my custom module?

Tags: hooks

I am using module [Mixpanel](https://www.drupal.org/project/mixpanel) in my site. And I want to override function of this module. Here is link where we can see the function or code which I need to alter [CODE NEED TO MODIFIED](http://pastebin.com/zesNrB6W)

Below is the code line which suggest that I can override this function :

```
    // Let other modules alter the defaults.
    drupal_alter('mixpanel_defaults', $properties, $account);
```

So from above line I am trying to override it with code as below, please let me know what I am doing wrong as it does not make any changes. However if I do same thing in main module it make changes but I don't want to make change in module but want to do in my custom module.

My custom module name: **custom**

```
function custom_mixpanel_defaults_alter($properties, $account) {

  $properties['distinct_id'] = $account->name;

}
```

When i see in `system` table weight of my `custom module` is `1000` and weight of `Mixpanel` is `0`.

Please suggest! Thanks

Comment: Alter functions takes the variables as references. Try using `&$properties` instead of just `$properties`, and `&$account` in place of `$account`.

Comment: Thank you. as per your suggestion it worked :) I think you can post it as answer if you want to so that it can help other users as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is how you define the parameters, which should be defined as `custom_mixpanel_defaults_alter(&$properties, $account)`.
PHP 5 automatically passes by reference any object passed to a function, but not the arrays. Since `$properties` is an array, you need to make the reference explicit.

Generally speaking, when you see a call to `drupal_alter()` like `drupal_alter('node_view', $build)`, and you need to implement that alter hook, check the second and third parameter are object or arrays; in the case they are array, you need to explicitly declare the parameter as reference. In this case, `hook_node_view_alter()` is defined as [`hook_node_view_alter(&$build)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7).

Comment: Thanks for explanation! and so it means we do not need to pass `$account as reference &$account` as its not array ?

Comment: Exactly: `$account` is an object, so PHP 5 will automatically pass it as reference.